# Ansible sefcontext not making fcontext permanent

Tags: centos, ansible, selinux

Trying to use Ansible on a CentOS 7 server to make a directory and sync files into it. That part is working. The problem is I get a `403 Forbidden` error when I try to access them from the browser. I understand that this is a `fcontext` problem with SELinux preventing Apache from accessing the files. I thought I had some Ansible code to handle this, but it is not adding the `fcontext`. I've manually set the `fcontext` on the CLI to make it work. If I remove the directory and run Ansible again, then the directory and files will have the right `fcontext`. Trying not to have to manually set the `fcontext` when I run this for my production server. Any ideas?

Here's the Ansible code used to set the `fcontext` and `restorecon` used.

```
- name: Allow apache to read
  sefcontext:
    target: "{{ dest_dir }}(/.*)?"
    setype: httpd_sys_content_t
    state: present

- name: Run restore context to reload selinux
  shell: restorecon -iRv "{{ dest_dir }}"
```

Comment: While reviewing the the module info on the [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/sefcontext_module.html) page, the examples show a very similar use case that has a slightly different syntax for the `restorecon` command to apply the updated policy to the filesystem. Have you tried your play with the second task using the syntax from the example? `command: restorecon -irv "{{ dest_dir }}"` I'll dig some more, but this might be a quick fix?

Comment: @0xSheepdog `-r` and `-R` are equivalent, so the command here is functionally identical to the one in the example.

Comment: Do you mean that this play succeeds but the fcontext was not created? Or does the play fail?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Those commanda have always been successfull and fcontext is not created. I either get "changed" or "ok".

Comment: Ah, forgot the r/R thing. I was also curious if you'd tried the `command` module instead of `shell`. Not sure it would matter.

Comment: Check the output of `semanage fcontext -l -C` after you ran this playbook, but before you manually added the file context.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on this issue. By listing the local customizations, I found that I had applied mutliple policies to the same file. You can view local policies with `semanage fcontext --list --locallist` and then run `semanage fcontext -d '/some/location(/.*)?'`

`man semanage-fcontext` for more info.